Continuous Wavelet Transform Coefficients
I am trying to reconstruct the continuous wavelet transform coefficients from Mathematica without using the ContinuousWaveletTransform function. I need to create this reconstruction for my data in a different application, but can not seem to attain the coefficients manually (the equation on the CWT details is not outputting the same coefficients). I can not use pywavelet because it does not have an InverseContinuousWavelet function. Please help me compute the coefficients correctly. Thanks for the help!!
E.g. Mexican Hat Wavelet


Welcome to Mma.SE. Thanks for taking the [tour]. Here it’s considered helpful to show your efforts and share your code in a well-formatted form instead of images or links to external files, so we can quickly Copy&Paste your code, test it, and see the problem you are facing. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question accordingly. This question in Meta could be useful.
